# Root's list of Victory points

Tags: root

Is there a quick-short list of each of the Root's factions and something like bullet points concisely explaining how each one scores? While playing I am constantly finding I need to ask for everyone's base sheet, or the rule book to try and guess out my opponent's strategies, or niche things they may attempt to pull. I enjoy the game but the asymmetry is a little hard for me to keep track of.

Reading the rules book is accurate, but long winded, all I really would like is a quick reminder of an aspect. The player board's are written more concisely but their layout is sometimes a little random, or lacking in some minor cases, not to mention that someone else is usually using it and can't afford to pass it around every time one asks.

Comment: I removed the scoring and win-condition tags as they are not needed on this question.

Comment: Any better tag suggestions? I'm not as familiar with B&C games as I would like to be.

Comment: Just need the game tag, the information you are looking for all falls under that and there isn't a need for special tags for it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the files section at BGG](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/237182/root/files):

[image]

[image]

Comment: The guide is misleading to the point of being wrong.  The cats/birds/lizards each have an item that says "points for building/roost/garden placed", but the cats earn points on placement, the birds earn points each turn based on placement, and the lizards earn points when they take an action (based on placement).  Those are three very different mechanisms.

Comment: @ArcanistLupus, I posted 2 pictures from two different files, which one are you refereeing?

Comment: The first one which concretely lists where points come from for each faction.

Comment: Its a quick-short list, it does not give all the info, just a reference list.